# 500 error: Output filter: Response body too large

Tags: wsod

I recently copied a drupal 7 site from my development server to my production server. Everything on the site seems to be working as expected, except for when I log in as the admin user and try to access `admin/modules`. When I go there I get a 500 "Internal Server Error" page. In the server's error log, I get: `ModSecurity: Output filter: Response body too large (over limit of 6291456, total not specified). [hostname "(my hostname)"] [uri "/drupal/index.php"] [unique_id "T4JOln8AAAEAAFLlyE4AAAAK"]`

(`unique_id` changes every time I get the error, but the other parts don't.)

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to disable the devel module. I don't know exactly what was causing the problem -- devel certainly doesn't write 6M of debugging information to the page locally.

Disabling the module was nontrivial since the problem was preventing the modules page from loading. I needed to disable devel on my development server, then sync the database on the production server with it.

Thanks to the folks on #drupal who helped me solve this.

Comment: This may just be masking the problem; it may come back at a later time.  You may want to consider @Yaazkal's answer as a long term solution.

Comment: @MPD Thanks for the suggestion. I will talk to my host about modesecurity if it comes up again. But on the other hand, if devel actually was bloating a normal drupal page to over 6M, that seems like genuinely unintended & pernicious behavior and I'm not surprised it was causing problems.

Answer (score 4):

ModSecurity is an Apache module (a Web Application Firewall) that protects sites from i.e SQL injectiosn, XSS attacks, prevents php shell execution and so on. You must contact your hoster and let them know because they need to change [modsec rules](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/) maybe.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think that if a normal drupal page actually was getting bloated to 6M, that's a reasonable thing to set off alarms for them. But this is good to know in case I run into a problem like this again and can't resolve it on my end.